# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES), another computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

[image]

I did a bundle install and it said I was missing a gem, so I did an gem install and I get this error.  What's the cause of this error and how do I fix it?  I saw similar threads but mine seems to have another parameter (macbook) to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the gem's GitHub repo, [.#base64_string_io_spec.rb](https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64/blob/v2.3.1/spec/.%23base64_string_io_spec.rb)
 is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `lebedev@MacBook-Pro-2.local.4354`. That's pretty clearly an accidental link to something in the maintainer's development environment, especially considering his last name is Lebedev. It's still in the most recent version of the gem, so I'd file an issue on the repo explaining what's happened and asking for the symlink to be removed if it isn't needed for some reason. You could try installing v2.2.0 of the gem in the meantime (doesn't look like the symlink is there) if you can't wait for this to be fixed.

I don't completely understand why this hasn't been raised as an issue by others, but [this Rubygems issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1623) suggests that Rubygems used to ignore symlinks when unpacking a gem on Windows but earlier this year started to implement them. I'm assuming this is a Windows environment based on the path in your error message.

As an aside, if you're using bundler, you shouldn't need to do a separate `gem install`. I'm curious what the "missing a gem" message said more precisely.